# Apache Curator double Locking issue with multiple services

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am currently using Apache Curator to externalize locking of a shared resource (a row within a database).
To summarize the issue,
I am running 2 instances of a service (using Spring Boot), lets call this Service A, and lets call the instances A1 and A2, which are deployed in different areas.
I lock on the id (primary key) of a table on a shared database which represents a file.

Within the code of Service A, I have created a singleton (BaseLockService) which handles all the locking within the project. This also means that for the 2 running instances, they each contain a singleton for processing the locking. The recipe i'm using is [Shared Reentrant Lock](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/shared-reentrant-lock.html)  which is using the InterProcessMutex class, however there is never a case for a reentrant lock. Its the class with the description closest to my needs.

The main process that runs is a @Scheduled one, and there is a 30 second delay between execution times.
In addition, I have created a bean for the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler which appends a UUID to the thread name and the pool size is 1.
Reason for this UUID is because without it, when A1 and A2 run concurrently, they both contain a Thread with the name "task-scheduler-1". This originally caused my issue
with locking because A1 might possess the lock and then at the same time while processing the file, A2 requests the lock and since they share the same name, Curator returns true on lock.acquire(), thus two instances possessing the same lock.

When running one instance, this isn't an issue. I see within ZooKeeper the ZNodes are being created, and I see the UUID which Curator generates for Ephemeral locks. 
When running two or more instances, the process sometimes gets into a race condition where A1 possesses the lock, then runs a lengthy process. Then A2 somehow obtains the lock, finishes the process quickly and releases the lock. Then when A1 is finished and tries to unlock, I get the following Exception:

```
[2019-07-09 21:53:54,485] ERROR [08c598b9-7254-408c-8ed2-0e5849ca2b19_task-scheduler-1] c.m.c.myApp.lock.BaseLockService.unlock - Can't unlock lock #com.myApp.lock.BaseLockService$LockableHandle@4ca8ddab
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /myapp/lock/files/1376112
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.delete(ZooKeeper.java:873)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.DeleteBuilderImpl$5.call(DeleteBuilderImpl.java:274)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.DeleteBuilderImpl$5.call(DeleteBuilderImpl.java:268)
    at org.apache.curator.connection.StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.callWithRetry(StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.java:64)
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:100)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.DeleteBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(DeleteBuilderImpl.java:265)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.DeleteBuilderImpl.forPath(DeleteBuilderImpl.java:249)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.DeleteBuilderImpl.forPath(DeleteBuilderImpl.java:34)
    at com.myApp.lock.BaseLockService.unlock(BaseLockService.java:174)
    at com.myApp.lock.BaseLockService.lambda$unlockAllIDs$0(BaseLockService.java:143)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at com.myApp.lock.BaseLockService.unlockAllIDs(BaseLockService.java:139)
```

Here is my Unit Test to replicate the situation:

```
@Test
public void baseLockTest() {
    List<Lockable> filesToProcess = new ArrayList<>();

    //For now only 1 to limit complexity
    Lockable fileToLock = FileSource.builder()
            .id(1)
            .build();

    filesToProcess.add(fileToLock);

    Runnable task = () -> {
        log.info("ATTEMPT LOCK");
        Set<BaseLockService.LockableHandle> lockedBatch = lockService.lockBatch(filesToProcess, 1);

        if (!lockedBatch.isEmpty()) {

            try {
                log.info("ATTEMPT FAKE PROCESS TIME SLEEP 100 MS");
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            log.info("ATTEMPT UNLOCK");
                lockService.unlockAll(lockedBatch);
        }
    };

    System.out.println("**********************************************************");

    //Simulate two Service instances of 1 thread
    int totalThreads = 2;
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalThreads);

    List<Future> locksProcessed = new ArrayList<>(totalThreads);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        locksProcessed.add(executorService.submit(task));
    }

    Future f;
    while(!locksProcessed.isEmpty()){
        Iterator<Future> iterator = locksProcessed.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            f = iterator.next();
            if(f.isDone()){
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("ALL DONE!!!");
}
```

Here is the lock and unlock methods within the BaseLockService:

```
    public Set<LockableHandle> lockBatch(final List<Lockable> desiredLock, final int batchSize) {
    Set<LockableHandle> effectivelyLocked = new HashSet<>();
    Iterator<Lockable> desiredLockIterator = desiredLock.iterator();

    while ((desiredLockIterator.hasNext()) && (effectivelyLocked.size() <= batchSize)) {
        Lockable toLock = desiredLockIterator.next();
        String lockPath = ZKPaths.makePath(getLockPath(), String.valueOf(toLock.getId()));
        InterProcessMutex lock = createMutex(lockPath);

        try {
            if (lock.acquire(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                LockableHandle handle = new LockableHandle(toLock, lock);
                effectivelyLocked.add(handle);
                locks.put(handle.getId(), handle);
            } else {
                log.warn(String.format("Object was not locked. Object id is %d, lock path is %s.",
                        toLock.getId(),
                        lockPath));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot lock path " + lockPath, e);
        }
    }

    log.info(String.format("%d object(s) were requested to lock. %d were effectively locked.",
            desiredLock.size(),
            effectivelyLocked.size()));

    return effectivelyLocked;
}

    public void unlock(final LockableHandle lockHandle) {
    boolean success = false;

    try {
        InterProcessMutex lock = lockHandle.getMutex();
        if (lock != null) {
            lock.release();
            client.delete()
                    .deletingChildrenIfNeeded()
                    .forPath(ZKPaths.makePath(getLockPath(), String.valueOf(lockHandle.getId())));
            success = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Can't unlock lock #" + lockHandle, e);
    } finally {
        locks.remove(lockHandle.getId());
    }

    log.info(String.format("The lock #%d was requested to be unlocked. Success = %b",
            lockHandle.getId(),
            success));
}
```

This is the init() method that is called after the service is instantiated:

```
    public void init() {
    log.info("Stating initialization of the Lock Service");
    locks = new HashMap<>();
    client = createClient();
    client.start();

    try {
        client.blockUntilConnected();
        if (client.isZk34CompatibilityMode()) {
            log.info("The Curator Framework is running in ZooKeeper 3.4 compatibility mode.");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        log.error("Cannot connect to ZooKeeper.", ie);
    }

    log.info("Completed initialization of the Lock Service");
}
```

- I've checked for connection issues and thats not a problem.
- No RECONNECTED, LOST, SUSPENDED messages found in the logs.
- Timeout of locks is not an issue because ZooKeeper doesn't expire any locks unless the session/connection dies.
- I've tried other Curator recipes and they don't work for my needs. Also they throw similar exceptions anyway.
- Version of Apache Curator is 4.2.0, ZooKeeper is 3.4.X

I'm not sure what is missing, but all out of options.
Thanks for any comments/suggestions

Comment: - Can you post the code for BaseLockService? - What is the session timeout you're using?

Comment: @Randgalt I added the additional code to the original question.  As for a session timeout, I don't explicitly set one. There is a method that looks for stale locks (older than 10 minutes) and releases those, however the time between lock and unlock is usually a matter of a few seconds.  I saw the message about ConnectionStateListener in the Error handling section of the Curator documentation but wasn't sure how to implement this. Also thought it might not be necessary in my case since I don't see any messages about LOST, SUSPENDED, etc states.

Comment: @Randgalt While debugging, I checked the CuratorZookeeperClient.state object and the sessionTimeoutMs  = 60,000. ConnectionTimeoutMs = 15,000 as well. In addition the CuratorZookeeperClient.state.zooKeeper object also has sessionTimeout = 60,000.

Comment: @Randgalt However, if I run this command:  (`((CuratorFrameworkImpl) lockService.client).getZooKeeper().getSessionTimeout()`) I get 40,000 so i'm not entirely sure which one is the proper value.  Sorry for the bombardment.

Comment: Still missing a lot of code where things might go wrong. But, maybe the lock paths aren't the same? Note, Curator has "InterProcessMultiLock" which might help you. But, without seeing more of the code I can't help much. i.e. what's the implementation for "getLockPath()"? Are we sure each process is generating the same paths?

Comment: getLockPath() is returning a static String of the root/parent ZNode, ex: /myapp/lock/files   and then each file we lock appends to it, for ex: /myapp/lock/files/1 , /myapp/lock/files/2, etc. I verified using ZKCLI that individual nodes are being created within that folder. This is what I wante, each service working on 1 file at a time and no two services working on the same file at once. InterProcessMultiLock mentions needing a List of paths, so since its the same root I just did (`Arrays.asList(getLockPath())`) but my test returns the same error. Is there anything more I can give you?

Comment: Shaun - if you can set up a test project of some kind I'm willing to run and see if I can find anything.

Comment: @Randgalt [Here it is](https://github.com/shaunmccready/locking-issue) and thanks a lot for the help! Its greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a number of issues in the [Locking Issue Example](https://github.com/shaunmccready/locking-issue) you sent. It could be these are particular to the example but if these are also in your code it will explain the problems you're seeing.

1. The Maven POM is incorrectly specified. Curator needs to know that it's in ZK 3.4.x compatibility mode - the way to do this is [described here](http://curator.apache.org/zk-compatibility.html). The TL;DR is exclude Zookeeper from the Curator dependency and add a direct dependency to Zookeeper 3.4.x.
2. The `locks` field in `BaseLockService` should be a `ConcurrentHashMap`
3. `BaseLockService#unlock` is trying to clean up the lock path by calling `client.delete()...`. This cannot work. There is an inherent race in this kind of code and is why Curator has the "Reaper" classes and also why I pushed Container Nodes into Zookeeper 3.5.x. Notice that it is this line of code that's producing the `NoNode` exception and not the Curator lock code. I suggest you get rid of that code and just not worry about it or move to Zookeeper 3.5.x.
4. I don't think `BaseLockService` should keep re-creating the `InterProcessMutex`. It should keep a map of them or something.

When I applied 1-3 above the test passes successfully (I tried multiple times). I've opened a [PR on your test project](https://github.com/shaunmccready/locking-issue/pull/1) with the 3 changes.

Comment: Thanks for going out of your way to help with this!! Very appreciated!
 As for point #4, I don't understand the reason to keep a collection(map). Would it be Map<String, InterProcessMutex> where String is the ZK path and reuse the InterProcessMutex? My concern was that when running two instances of my service, I would have 2 systems fighting for locks and managing it at the same time.  It was a crude way but I ran two instances of the tests side by side and checked the timestamp in the logs and saw that they shared the lock. No lock overlapped at any point so I hope this is enough to trust it

Comment: > 2 systems fighting for locks
Yeah maybe - I'd have to see the use case to comment further. But, if new allocations are working that's likely fine.

Comment: I'm going to test it in a parallel environment over the night and see how it works. Essentially the service looks for all configured sources of files and seeings which has new files. It processes 1 source at a time. Once new files are found, we add it to a list of files to download and send it to a separate component to download the files. Since there's two instances both looking for new files, I want to lock the current source being search so they both don't process the same one, thus preventing a duplicate entry in the list of files to download.